# Vi: Visual Studio like tooltip summary of lib/api/object/function

Tags: vim

Like Visual Studio when you type-in a tooltip shows you the summary (documentation) of lib/objects/functions etc.

Suppose, I'm experimenting with [DataMapper](http://datamapper.org/). I would like to see what it has and what each of them can do (purpose) without leaving vim. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Although I'm doing PHP development, not Ruby, I think this will also work for Ruby:
For PHP (Drupal) I generate a tags file with ctags and configure vim to use this tagfile by setting the `tags`-option. (see `:help tags`).

Now when I start typing a function-name I can press `CTRL-X CTRL-O` to start Omnicompletion. Vim show a list of all possible completions and you can select next/previous suggestions with `CTRL-N` and `CTRL-P`. When selecting a completion Vim also shows the function declaration in a preview window.

You can close the preview window with the `:pclose`-command.

The preview will only show up if the `completeopt`-settings contains the `preview` value (see `:help 'completeopt'`)